# Why do I get a decimal error when I substract two numbers with Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, decimal

I have made a simplified example that shows my issue. When substracting one number from another I get a false result. I could round the result with 2 decimals, but this is more a workaround.

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim Sale As Double
    Dim Fee As Double
    Dim Payment As Double
    Payment = 104953.98
    Sale = 105000
    Fee = Sale - Payment
End Sub
```

Testing the code in the immediate window shows that Fee is calculated to 46,0200000000041 which is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the naming of the variables you might want to try this

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Sale As Currency
    Dim Fee As Currency
    Dim Payment As Currency
    Payment = 104953.98
    Sale = 105000
    Fee = Sale - Payment
End Sub
```

You also should read on [Floating-point arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)  and https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: I like the solution Storax - very simple.

I'm not a VBA blackbelt, so I did not know I could dim as currency - this solved the issue.

I still don't understand the reason why I get the error when I dim as Double

This is my first question here - now I just need to close the question and mark your answer as the solution

Answer (score 0):

If you need them to be Doubles for some reason, convert them to Decimals before you do the math:

```
Fee = CDec(Sale) - CDec(Payment)
```

[Type Conversion Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions)

Comment: Thank you for your help braX. I will go with the solution provided by Storax

Comment: His is better if you can change the types of variables you are using.